# Google Cloud Messaging for Android works from server to client, but also viceversa(from client to server)?

Tags: android, cloud, google-cloud-messaging

stackoverflow fellows,

Since I am very new in Cloud Computing matters, I would like to ask you a question: Google Cloud Messaging for Android works from server to client, but also viceversa(from client to server)?

I am asking you this, because I am currently developing an Android application. The structure, in general lines, it's something like: I would like to use my laptop as a server - and perform all the computations here. Then, from my server (laptop), to send everything in the cloud, and from the cloud, directly to my Android running device. I want to perform the computing and database storage on my local server (because, since I am a student, I won't have enough money to actually pay for a server from google (let's say), so I am focusing on what's free and suitable to my needs) and just communicate with my Android device using Google Cloud Messaging for Android. (I want my application to be independent from the hardware of my mobile device, and also, I want to write the program that will perform the computations on my server in Java).

I know that I can send messages from the server to my device(through cloud), but the question is: can I also send messages from my device to the server ? I am asking this, because the computations will be made after I submit something from my device (basically, my Android application will be an interface, from where I can send the data to my server (through cloud) and then receive (also through cloud) the results of the computation on my device)

According to what I've been currently reading (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) it seems that I can only send messages from the server to my device, but I decided to ask, since, so far, was the only free messaging framework(using cloud) I have found.

Thank you.

Comment: "because, since I am a student, I won't have enough money to actually pay for a server from google" -- since Google App Engine is free for low volumes, you may wish to reconsider your rationale.

Comment: Give a look to openshift from redhat as well... they have free plans as well for low performance instances.

Comment: Hmm, I will make some research related to that, thank you! Do I need to use also web services ?

Comment: Actually, it's not meant to necessary be "low performance", just the volume of data is not going to be very very big.

Comment: It's not free, but I use a Raspberry Pi which is a very cheap, single board, low power computer as my Apache server to send GCM messages. It's fine for low volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android works from server to client, but
>   also viceversa(from client to server)?

Sorry but GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) is only made up for sending Push Notification from server to device. Not for Viceversa.

> I know that I can send messages from the server to my device(through
>   cloud), but the question is: can I also send messages from my device
>   to the server ?

For sending the message or anything(For Example: Photo,files..) to Server why Don't you Use Web services for it. I think it will Be suitable according to your Needs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use GCM Cloud Connection Server to send messages from device to server.

Paragraph from this page:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

> The GCM Cloud Connection Server (CCS) allows third party servers to communicate with Android devices by establishing a persistent TCP connection with Google servers using the XMPP protocol. This communication is asynchronous and **bidirectional**.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct what KashifB wrote:

> You can use GCM Cloud Connection Server to send messages from device
>   to server.

But keep in mind that **Messages with Payload** have a **size limit of 4kb** per message.